# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n!}{n^n}}x^n$ and $x\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

i computed $|x|<e$ by using $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigg |\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\bigg |$. But shouldn't there be more solutions since $x\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: These are different questions!!!

Comment: All that changes is that $x$ is now a complex number in the open disc centred at $0$, radius $e$, rather than on the open interval $(-e, e)$.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic the answer in the provided dupe covers this question.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I don't think it does. The question here is about how complex numbers affects the process for finding the radius/region of convergence, and neither of the answers in the dupe target address this. They only go as far as the OP went themselves: to conclude the radius is $e$.

Comment: @TheoBendit how does showing the terms don't go to zero along the radius of convergence insufficient?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well, because that's not the question. It's not about convergence along the boundary of the disk of convergence, but (I think) a more general concern about working in $\Bbb{C}$ rather than $\Bbb{R}$. I'm thinking the OP was concerned that the radius of convergence might be larger in $\Bbb{C}$ than it is in $\Bbb{R}$. It's not, of course, but that's what would go in an answer.